# Is it profitable to use Amazon EC2 to mine litecoins?

Tags: litecoin, mining-profitability, amazon-web-services

I saw that mining BTC with CPU is not profitable anymore, and that you'd [lose money](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8405.0) mining bitcoin. Is the same thing true of litecoin?

Comment: While the other question was technically about mining BTC and as such is not technically a duplicate, LTC mining on an EC2 node was discussed in an answer to [this question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2172/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be worth it, but generally what happens is if it ever is worth it then a huge number of people start doing it until the prices of EC2 are driven up and it is no longer profitable. Here is a good blog post about the subject:

http://da-data.blogspot.com/2013/12/briefly-profitable-alt-coin-mining-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Only if you use the micro instance with a free account for the first year.